# Beginner with regular expressions; need help writing a specific query - space, followed by 1-3 numbers, followed by any number of letters

Tags: python, regex, expression

I'm working with some poorly formatted HTML and I need to find every instance of a certain type of pattern.  The issue is as follows:

a space, followed by a 1 to 3 digit number, followed by letters (a word, usually).  Here are some examples of what I mean.

```
hello 7Out
how 99In
are 123May
```

So I would be looking for the expression to get the "7Out", "99In", "123May", etc.  The initial space does not need to be included.  I hope this is descriptive enough, as I am literally just starting to expose myself to regular expressions and am still struggling a bit.  In the end, I will want to count the total number of these instances and add the total count to a df that already exists, so if you have any suggestions on how to do that I would be open to that as well.  Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: The regex you want is `\d{1,3}\w+`

Comment: ...and if the initial space is optional, then  `r'\x20?\d{1,3}[A-Za-z]+'`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen your regex allows matches of more than 3 leading digits....

Comment: @RayToal that's probbably the fault of SO markup.  It eats leading spaces

Comment: @RayToal The initial space isn't optional.  How would yours change to reflect that?

Comment: Sorry that may have been confusing.  What I meant is that there will always be a leading space.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far (forming a [mcve]), example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [tour] and [ask].

Comment: If you are "literally just starting" with regex, you should be reading tutorials and guides, not asking strangers on the Internet to write expressions for you.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I mean the `\w`matches digits so saying `\d{1,3}\w+` matches a string of 20 digits, 3 from `\d{1,3}` and the next 17 from `\w+`

Comment: @JRE0714 Remove the question mark if the leading space is **required**: so you have r'\x20\d{1,3}[A-Za-z]+' ... The string `\x20` matches a space character. If you allow tabs or newlines in addition to spaces this gets much more complex. Happy regex learning! It's a huge topic. You have to be super precise with these things.

Comment: @RayToal Thank you!  I really appreciate your help.

Comment: https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression will be:    `r'\w\s(\d{1,3}[a-zA-Z]+)'`

So in order to get count you can use len() upon list returned by findall. The code will be

```
import re
string='hello 70qwqeqwfwe123 12wfgtr123 34wfegr123 dqwfrgb'
result=re.findall(r'\w\s(\d{1,3}[a-zA-Z]+)',string)
print "result = ",result #this will give you all the found occurances as list
print "len(result) = ",len(result) #this will give you total no of occurances.
```

The result will be:

```
result = ['70qwqeqwfwe', '12wfgtr', '34wfegr']
len(result) = 3
```

Hint: findall will evaluate regular expression and returns results based on grouping. I'm using that to solve this problem.

Try these:

```
re.findall(r'(\w\s((\d{1,3})[a-zA-Z]+))',string)
re.findall(r'\w\s((\d{1,3})[a-zA-Z]+)',string)
```

To get an idea about regular expressions refer [python re](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html), [tutorials point](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_reg_expressions.htm) and to play with the matching characters use [this.](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: @RayToal thanks for pointing out the mistake. I hope bug fixed.